# i want to trim a rupee symbol but its not working in a single quote

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void paymentHasMade (object sender, EventArgs e)   
{
   decimal total= 0;
   try
   {
      total = decimal.Parse (txtamounttopay.Text.TrimStart('रु')) - decimal.Parse(txtpaymentamount.Text);
   }
}
```

Comment: what's in `Text` coming?

Comment: it showing me a error:Too many characters in character literal

Comment: what is the input of textbox i mean

Comment: in text its returning a numeric value

Comment: show that what is in it coming?

Comment: The problem is that `'रु'` is unicode and cannot be held in a single `char`.

Comment: the compiler is treating a rupee symbol as 2 characters so i cannot insert it in a single quote. if i am trying to insert in a double quote it is mismatching the trimstart method

Comment: You have to do it by hand, check with `txtamounttopay.Text,StartsWith("रु")` and in that case `txtamounttopay.Text.Substring("रु".Length)`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `string.Replace` instead.

```
total = decimal.Parse (txtamounttopay.Text.Replace("रु", string.Empty)) 
      - decimal.Parse(txtpaymentamount.Text);
```